# Convert IEnumerable<T> to object[,] C#

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I'm attempting to build a generic method that will convert any IEnumerable to an object[,]. The purpose of this is for insertion into excel via ExcelDNA which ideally requires 2d object arrays.

I am new to reflection and need some serious help to fill in the gaps here.
The code posted below is what I have so far, what I need will be to get the propertie of T at index i of DataSource in the outer loop. In the inner loop then get the values of each property in turn and insert into the object[,].

Any help appreciated.
Thanks
Richard

```
    public object[,] ConvertListToObject<T>(IEnumerable<T> DataSource)
    {
        int rows = DataSource.Count();

        //Get array of properties of the type T
        PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
        propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public);

        int cols = propertyInfos.Count();   //Cols for array is the number of public properties

        //Create object array with rows/cols
        object[,] excelarray = new object[rows, cols];

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) //Outer loop
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++) //Inner loop
            {
                object[i,j] =             //Need to insert each property val into j index
            }
        }
        return excelarray;
       }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're pretty close. A few pointers:

- The outer loop will need to be a `foreach` loop, as you can't, in general, efficiently access an `IEnumerable` by index.
- [`GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyaxdd3x.aspx) requires either `BindingFlags.Static` or `.Instance` in order to return anything.
- You get the actual value by calling [`propertyInfos[j].GetValue`](http://www.google.co.uk/url?q=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx&sa=U&ei=dBhsUMC_Ooek0QXKs4HICA&ved=0CBUQFjAA&usg=AFQjCNHbXNOOgl7GdLGriwCCRontn673JQ), passing in the `T`-instance you want to get it from and an array of indexer values - null for regular properties, but if your objects might have indexed properties you'll either need to figure out something to pass here or handle an exception which might be thrown otherwise.

I get something like this:

```
public object[,] ConvertListToObject<T>(IEnumerable<T> DataSource)
{
    int rows = DataSource.Count();
    //Get array of properties of the type T
    PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
    propertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties(
        BindingFlags.Public |
        BindingFlags.Instance); // or .Static
    int cols = propertyInfos.Length;
    //Create object array with rows/cols
    object[,] excelarray = new object[rows, cols];
    int i = 0;
    foreach (T data in DataSource) //Outer loop
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) //Inner loop
        {
            excelarray[i, j] = propertyInfos[j].GetValue(data, null);
        }
        i++;
    }
    return excelarray;
}
```

Comment: The documentation for `GetValue` says the second argument should be null for non-indexed properties.  This will reduce the burden on the garbage collector.

Comment: Fair enough, I stole a couple of fixes from your answer, too :-)

Comment: There's also a fix I mentioned but didn't put in my code, I've fixed that now.

Answer (score 1):

Since you can't index into an enumerable, you should enumerate it in a foreach loop while incrementing a counter, rather than using a for loop.

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var row in DataSource)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        excelarray[i,j] = propertyInfos[j].GetValue(row, null);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    public object[,] ConvertListToObject<T>(IEnumerable<T> dataSource)
    {
        if (dataSource != null)
        {
            var rows = dataSource.Count();
            var propertyInfos = typeof (T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public);
            var cols = propertyInfos.Length;
            var excelarray = new object[rows,cols];
            var i = 0;
            foreach (var data in dataSource)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < cols; j++)
                {
                    excelarray[i, j] = propertyInfos[j].GetValue(data, null);
                }
                i++;
            }
            return excelarray;
        }
        return new object[,] {};
    }
```